# Unable to extract a simple data from response using jmeter

Tags: ajax, regex, jmeter, extract

I have got a simple ajax response and I am trying to extract the value of orderId and orderItemId from the below response. I tried json path post processor as well as regular expression extractor.

I gave like this in the post processor

"orderId": ["(.+?)"] 
template-$1$
Match No-1,  in the Regular Expression. But it is not extracting the value.

```
/*
{"orderId": ["1389104"],"orderItemId": ["7900094"],
}
*/
```

Any idea why? I have extracted more complicated values using regex. This one is a bit strange.Is there any difference if it is an ajax response?

Comment: Did you checked the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Regular Expression: `"orderId": \["(.+?)"]`

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but `[` is a special character is regex, you need to escape it with `\`, use `Regular Expression Extractor`

```
Regular Expression: orderId": \["(\d+)

Template $1$ 

Match No 1
```